# add class to an li generated from a json call

Tags: jquery

I have a little script like so:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('website.com?format=json', function(data){

          var tags = [];
          $.each(data.product.tags, function(index, tag){
            tags.push('<li class="tag">' + tag.title + '</li>');
          });
          $( "<ul/>", { html: tags.join( '' ) }).appendTo('.productInfo.4567 .icons');
          $(".productInfo.4567 .icons ul li:last-child").addClass("last");

        });
      });
```

In the array there's a tag called "H0". What i try to do is to add a class "blue" to the "li" when a tag equals "H0".

I tried things like this:

```
          if(tags == 'H0'){
            $(".productInfo.4567 .icons .tag").addClass("blue");
          }
```

But that doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think tags will ever equal "H0". Probably the easiest thing for you to do would be

```
   var tags = [];
      $.each(data.product.tags, function(index, tag){

   var className = tag.title === "H0" ? "tag blue" : "tag"; //ternary operation. If title is "H0", use both tag and blue classes, otherwise just use tag.

        tags.push('<li class="' + className + '">' + tag.title + '</li>');
      });
```

I believe that should work (provided I understand what you are trying to do correctly).

Comment: Never heard of this :( Thanks it works perfectly. Just one more question: How to use your code if you want to check 2 tag.titles. So check if it is "H0" or "H20"??

Comment: var className = tag.title === "H0" || tag.title === "H20" ? "tag blue" : "tag"; That is fine if there are only two conditions, but if you wanted to add an H30, H50, H60, etc... you would probably want to take a different approach.